# How to change year field in input type="date" to be entered from the front

Tags: html, date, validation, input

Is there an easy way to change the year in a html input type date to be inputted from the front? When typing the year in this html input the last digit of the year is changed first, followed by the third etc. I want the year field to input from the front, so the first digit is entered first, then the second etc. Any ideas?

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```